# Cloudformation "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup" object with the Reason "No default VPC for this user"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a stack in Cloudformation - I'm using the Windows Roles and Features sample template from here for this:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/sample-templates-applications-us-east-1.html

I've been testing cloudformation to see if it may be something I'd like to try. While launching the Stack, I keep running into an error when creating the "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup" object with the Reason "No default VPC for this user"

I currently have 1 VPC with a bunch of different subnets. I've added a section in my JSON to specify the VPC and subnet but am still getting this error when I create the stack. Here is what I have added:

"VpcId" : {
      "Type" : "String",
      "Description" : "VpcId of your existing Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)"
    },

```
"Subnets" : {
  "Type" : "CommaDelimitedList",
  "Description" : "The list of SubnetIds, for at least two Availability Zones in the region in your Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)"
},
```

Anyone know how to fix this? Or what I may be missing. Again as I said, I'm literally using the sample template. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide a VPC id:

- If you have an existing VPC then supply its VPC id, for example: `"VpcId" : "vpc-12345678"`.
- If you're creating the VPC in the same CloudFormation template then you'll need to reference it, for example `"VpcId" : { "Ref" : "myvpc" }` were `myvpc` is the resource name of the [AWS::EC2::VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-vpc.html) resource you created in the template.

I have also seen this error message when using CDK if you attempt to create a self-referencing security group rule, for example:

```
new ec2.CfnSecurityGroup(this, "mysg1"), {
  groupName: "sg1",
  securityGroupEgress: [
  ],
  securityGroupIngress: [
    {
      ipProtocol: "-1",
      fromPort: -1,
      toPort: -1,
      sourceSecurityGroupName: "sg1",
    },
  ],
  vpcId,
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added a Parameter to specify default VPC. The next issue I'm having is that upon the creation of the "AWS::EC2::Instance" I run into the same error. "No default VPC found for this user"  

Once I add the "VpcId" reference in the properties I get the error: "WindowsServer Encountered unsupported property VpcId" - The documentation then shows that VpcId is not a valid Property for the "EC2::Instance" value. "

So how can I specify which VPC to use if I can't add the VpcId item to my instance?

Comment: Instances (in VPC) are launched into subnets. VPCs comprise one or more subnets. You need to supply the SubnetId when launching an instance.  See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html.